# How To Add Selected to First Data After Populate From MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

My Table

```
ID | data
1 | SMG 20
2 | SMG 5
3 | SMG 21
4 | SMG 34
5 | SMG 40
.....
```

Then I display data into <'select'> tag

```
SELECT data FROM mytable ORDER BY ID DESC
```

How to add 'selected' to first option ?
In this case no default value, so first data is selected.

Comment: write you code, where you creating `<select>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code below might help you

```
<select name="food">
<option value="0">Please Select Option</option>
<option value="pizza" <?php if($options=="pizza") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >pizza</option>
<option value="coffee" <?php if($options=="coffee") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >coffee</option>
</select>
```